# How to add some types in PowerShell 6 (I can do in PowerShell 5)

Tags: powershell, add-type

I wrote a script to display a message box. It works well in PowerShell 5, but doesn't PowerShell 6.
How can I make it work?

Script I wrote(extracted):

```bsh
function test
{
     [CmdletBinding()]
     param([Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)][string]$directory)

     Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
     Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Visualbasic
     Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

  #----------------------------
}
```

Error message:

> Add-Type : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Owner\System.Windows.Forms.dll'
>   because it does not exist. At
>   C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\sample\trans-search.ps1:8 char:6
>   +      Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
>   +      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Owner\System.Windows.Forms.dll:String) [Add-Type],
>   ItemNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think they didn't work on porting Forms until .NET Core 3.0. You may be on an old version, or it's not fully ported yet. [What's new in .NET Core 3.0 (Preview 6)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell 6 - support for Windows GUI libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209881/powershell-6-support-for-windows-gui-libraries)

Comment: Note that in ps5 you can do something like:  `using assembly System.Windows.Forms; using namespace System.Windows.Forms; [messagebox]::show('hello world')`

Comment: Maybe you can use a web browser to display things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those types aren't available in PowerShell 6.x. They are supposed to become available in PowerShell v7 but aren't in preview 2

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't wait for PowerShell 7