# Why can't powershell 6 aka pwsh.exe load System.Windows.Forms

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell

I have two different versions of powershell on my machine.

- powershell.exe  5.1.18362.145
- pwsh.exe        6.2.3

With powershell.exe I can execute

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$oReturn=[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("This is the Message text")
```

But with pwsh.exe I get the error

```
Exception calling "LoadWithPartialName" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
At line:1 char:2
+  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Fo ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileLoadException
```

What's up here?  Every time I opened powershell over the last 6 months I was shell spammed and told to upgrade to powershell 6. Now I have and the above doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell 6 - support for Windows GUI libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209881/powershell-6-support-for-windows-gui-libraries)